# .net ASP.NET Identity - more users

Tags: asp.net, .net, identity

Is it possible to be logged by more accounts at the same time? I mean at localhost.
For example: one user for one browser tab/window.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how other browsers work, but with IE you can select *File - New Session*. That opens a new browser window that you can then use to login with a different account.

Comment: @user1429080 - thanks, will try

Comment: For chrome we can add multiple user from **chrome://settings/createProfile**